# Save a form in flask ?

Tags: python, flask, peewee

i have code for form , i want to save the data through a form.
custom form is :-

```
<form class="well span12 c1" name="contacts" method="POST">
<label>First Name</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Your First Name" class="span12" required  name="firstname" >
            <label>Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Your Last Name" class="span12" required   name="lastname" >
            <label>Email Address</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Your email address" class="span12" required  name="email" >
            <label>Subject</label>
            <select class="span12" name="subject" id="subject" required >
                <option value="na" selected="">Choose One:</option>
                <option value="service">General Customer Service</option>
                <option value="suggestions">Suggestions</option>
                <option value="product">Product Support</option>
            </select>


            <label>Message</label>
            <textarea rows="8" class="input-xlarge span12" id="message" name="message" required ></textarea>

        <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" style="border-radius:0px;" type="submit">Send</button>

</form>
```

views.py :-

```
 @app.route('/contact' ,  methods = ['GET' , 'POST' ])
def contact():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user = user_email(firstname = request.form['firstname'] , 
            lastname = request.form['lastname'],
            email = request.form['email'],
            subject = request.form['subject'],
            message = request.form['message'])
        user.save()
        return render_template('index.html')
    else:
        return render_template('contact.html')
```

there is an error of AttributeError: 'Database' object has no attribute 'model'. Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: The error message alone is helpful, but not helpful enough. Edit the question and post the full traceback. It should include line numbers. Look at the lines in the traceback that relate to your code to help pinpoint the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you setup a database, and connected to it? It should look something like this:

```
# define a database connection
database = peewee.SqliteDatabase('my.db')

class BaseModel(peewee.Model):
    class Meta:
        # this is likely the missing part of your model
        # you need to tell the model which database connection to use.
        database = database

class User(BaseModel):
    first_name = peewee.CharField()
    last_name = peewee.CharField()
    email = peewee.CharField()
    subject = peewee.CharField()
    message = peewee.CharField()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form class="well span12 c1" name="contacts" method="POST" action="{{ url_for('contact') }}"> 
  <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span6">
            <label>First Name</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Your First Name" class="span12" required  name="firstname" >
            <label>Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Your Last Name" class="span12" required   name="lastname" >
            <label>Email Address</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Your email address" class="span12" required  name="email" >
            <label>Subject</label>
            <select class="span12" name="subject" id="subject" required >
                <option value="na" selected="">Choose One:</option>
                <option value="service">General Customer Service</option>
                <option value="suggestions">Suggestions</option>
                <option value="product">Product Support</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="span6">
            <label>Message</label>
            <textarea rows="8" class="input-xlarge span12" id="message" name="message" required ></textarea>
        </div>

        <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" style="border-radius:0px;" type="submit">Send</button>
    </div>
</form>
```